# Need help lining some buttons

Tags: html, css

I can't make those buttons stay on the same line, I think it has something to do with 'clear' in css because if I deactivate almost all the css attributes for the buttons (using chrome's inspect element thing) they finally line up.

This is the page: http://framework.aluxian.com/login.php

Comment: try setting a position: absolute; and top:200px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Wrap them by a `<div>` and clear it.</strike> Just un-`clear` the buttons. Here is the code I've just tried in my Firebug:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" id="loginform">
<!-- ... -->
<button style="clear: none;" class="button_colour round_all" id="loginbutton" onclick="document.forms['loginform'].submit();"><!-- ... --></button>
<button style="clear: none;" class="button_colour round_all" id="registerbutton" onclick="location.href='register.php'"><!-- ... --></button>
<!-- ... -->
</form>
```

And yeah, I believe you don't need all those `onclick`'s

Comment: There is no need for the extra div container because the `clear: none` will already align the buttons..

Answer (score 2):

Just override the `clear` property from `.button` in the `#loginbutton` and `#registerbutton` class and the buttons will align horizontal.

```
#loginbutton,
#registerbutton {
    clear: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#registerbutton {
    clear: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 30px 55px;
}

#loginbutton {
    clear: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 30px 55px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `clear: both;` on `#loginbutton` (line 425), and `button` (line 12) in your main.css stylesheet.

Remove that attribute for both or specify `clear:none;` on `#loginbutton`.  That will supersede the `button` attribute.  If another button were added after `#registerbutton`, you would want to add `clear:both;` to it as well.